What minimum permission required to deploy SPFx web part
Wanted to confirm what minimum rights are required to deploy a spfx web part in site collection level app catalog. I tried in my dev tenant and i see Full control rights can deploy the .sppkg web part to app catalog.
Tried to use contribute rights-> Failed,
Full control- Success,
Site coll admin-Success.

see (on: sharepoint.stackexchange.com): Deploy option missing after adding spfx webpart package to app catalog

Thanks! This post is right -with owners rights i cannot see deploy option in ribbon. So minimum we need is site coll admin.
